# Meaning of 「ブリった」

Tags: translation, slang, song-lyrics

I was listening to a Japanese rap the other day, and came across the word 「ブリった」. A comment on [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxB6l4cpFW8) said it meant "get high". I tried searching for the meaning online, and the only answer I could find was [this answer](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1081889475) that says it's probably a contraction of 「ぶりっこした」.

It doesn't make a ton of sense to me, cause in context the verse is 「ブリった、みんなが」 which if either one of the definitions were correct, would loosely mean "everyone got high" or "everyone was acting cute". Does anyone know definitely what this slang means and where its origins are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 大麻を吸うこと：　ブリる
>
> シンナーを吸うこと：　ラリる
>
> 覚せい剤をすること：　パキる

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1219422067

According to the information, ぶりった means "smoke weed."